# what is wrong with this sql query?

Tags: sql, mysql

what is wrong with this sql query. i cant figure it out.

```
    $query = "SELECT *
    FROM tagPairs
    WHERE (tag1Id IN ($tag1Id, $tag2Id))
    AND (tag2Id IN ($tag1Id, $tag2Id))";
```

error code:

Couldn't execute query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' ))
        AND (tag2Id IN (, ))' at line 3

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$tag1Id` and `$tag2Id` are both null, or empty strings. The simplest solutions is probably to explicitly cast them into numerical values:

```
$tag1Id = intval($tag1Id);
$tag2Id = intval($tag2Id);
$query = "SELECT *
    FROM tagPairs
    WHERE (tag1Id IN ($tag1Id, $tag2Id))
    AND (tag2Id IN ($tag1Id, $tag2Id))";
```

Answer (score 3):

`$tag1Id` and `$tag2Id` are empty.

That's why your error says `(tag2Id IN (, ))`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$tag1Id` and `$tag2Id` are empty strings. Assign a value to them and it should work fine.

Also, selecting * is a bad idea. Select the columns you need explicity.

Comment: what if i dont need any column. i just wanted to check if a row exists in a table. what should i use instead of * then?

Comment: in that case use "select 1 where exists (select * from ... )"